# compare 2 managed object addresses in unmanaged code

Tags: c#, pointers, unmanaged, managed

breaking my head to get solution to a problem, 
I need to compare 2 managed object in unmanaged code.

i.e
compare if I already accessed to managed object,the compaction is in unmanaged code.

my first idea is to pass the memory address, but i got no success getting the object address in C# 
(also can't pin the object)

I'm using existing c++ code that already implement the comparison by comparing addresses.

some code example to get the idea:

C# code:

```
Object obj ; 

if (IsObjAccessed(obj))
{
        // do something
}
else
{
   // SerializeObject
   SaveAccessedObject(obj);
}
```

====================================================

c++ code:

```
bool IsObjAccessed(UINT8* address) ;

void SaveAccessedObject(UINT8* address) ;
```

Comment: Managed objects do **not** have a fixed address.  The garbage collector moves them when it compacts the heap.  This can happen at any time, there's no way to predict when a collection will trigger.  There's Object.ReferenceEquals() to check if two object references refer to the same object.  But that's highly unlikely to be useful in the scenario you are trying to implement.   Which otherwise is very mysterious.  Don't "save" objects.

Comment: .NET has good serialization support, so forget about C++ and go to simple pure .NET solution.

Comment: one idea that I thought of is to pass obj.GetHashCode as a pointer.

Comment: Using `GetHashCode` is not reliable. Two different objects could have identical hash codes.

Comment: Build some kind of key from the object's data, I suppose. Or pass a unique object ID to the C++ code from the C# code. There are lots of options, but which would work depends in large part on your objects, how you use them, etc. You could also just use the .NET serialization to serialize the objects to a memory stream, and then pass the buffer to the C++ to store it as a blob.

Comment: Hi, i gave up and implemented this mechanism in C#.   thanks :)